# Naming a cyclic buffer class for timed samples?

Tags: c++, language-agnostic, naming

Given:

```
class Buf {
  // has fixed buffer size, forming a cyclic buffer tor t->v pairs
  void add(time_type t, value_type v); // adds value v at time t, overwriting the oldest buffered value
  value_type get(time_type t); // returns the value at time t1 for t1 <= t < t2 (for t1 and t2 datapoints in the buffer)
  ...
};
```

What would you call this class?

I admit it is somehow subjective, but it shouldn't lead to or require extended discussion of the answers, so I hope it's OK. :-)

---

So far I'm thinking of `RecentValueBuffer` since the class maps (recent) timestamps to values corresponding to these timestamps. I'm a bit unsure about "recent" because that seems to imply a short time-range/number of samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ask yourself if the user of the class needs to know, or care, that the internal implementation is a circular buffer. If not, name it something that makes it clear what the purpose of the class is: maybe something like `TimeMap` since it seems to be mapping values to discrete points in time. Then you can always change the internal implementation to something else (say, a Hashtable) without changing the name of your class.

If it's important to the semantics that it's always a circular buffer, then consider making it a generic container `CircularBuffer` or the like and use templates to define the types of the keys and values.

Answer (score 1):

Some combination of a few meaningful aspects of its purpose and design:

- Fixed_Sized
- FIFO
- Circular
- Buffer
- Recent
- Last_N
- Time_Window

Choose one or combine however many you like until you're happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

[CircularBuffer or RingBuffer](http://www.google.com/search?q=circular+buffer)

I wrote one recently for keeping a running average (called RunningAverage), and referred to it my comments as a 'ring buffer', so I apparently that's my preference. :) Probably because it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the STL-compliant [boost::circular_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html) here rather than roll your own version of that structure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I'll go with an underlying `vector` though, as that seems less complex and I need to wrap the circular buffer anyway to implement the `get` function. (Less complex: Think iterator invalidation etc.)